# How do I configure Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol to return a FTP server's IP address along with the interface IP address?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhcp-option

Given that there is a dhcp client, a relay agent and dhcp server. There is also another ftp server. Requirement is that the client starts the DORA process and the server responds with IP address and also sends the ftp server’s address. Is there any configuration or DHCP option available to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see one in [RFC2132](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2132). Did you check before asking?

Comment: What are you expecting the client to do with it?  You can set custom values for almost anything but the client needs to know how to use the cutom values.

Comment: The vm/physical switch running the dhcp client will download a file from this server's IP address. This not necessarily needs to be a tftp server. Client can use wget/http to download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DHCP option 66 (Boot server host name) and can provide FTP address as a string(ftp://2.21.22.23). 
Otherwise you can use vendor specific options for acquiring FTP server address in DHCP request.

You can also set this to https://2.21.22.23 for https. By default it is tftp://2.21.22.23.

Answer (score 1):

There are some DHCP options for TFTP, but I don't find anything for FTP. See IANA's [*Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Bootstrap Protocol (BOOTP) Parameters*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml).

It is possible that there is a vendor specific value in an option for what you are trying to do, but you will need to discuss that with the vendor.